# Batch file to do everything in a directory

Tags: batch-file

So I'm looking to make a jar to take everything in a directory of type "jar" then have it list it's directory name, and it's filename:

So something like this:

```
Listing of files in Directory c:\abc\123

myJar1.jar
myJar2.jar
...
myJar10.jar
```

How I want my output to appear is something like:

```
<jar href="123/myJar1.jar"/>
<jar href="123/myJar2.jar"/>
...
<jar href="123/myJar10.jar"/>
```

I've been having a lot of issues with this script, I can't seem to take variable that I'm setting and get them to append to text how I normally do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for an intermediate file, nor environment variables.

```
@echo off
>myJars.txt (for %%D in (.) do for %%F in (*.jar) do echo ^<jar href="%%~nD/%%F"/^>)
```

If you really must include hidden and system files, then the following longer version works

```
@echo off
>myJars.txt (for %%D in (.) do for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.jar') do echo ^<jar href="%%~nD/%%F"/^>)
```

Both of the above can be reformatted to be a bit more readable:

```
:: excludes hidden and system files
@echo off
>myJars.txt (
  for %%D in (.) do (
    for %%F in (*.jar) do (echo ^<jar href="%%~nD/%%F"/^>)
  )
)

:: includes hidden and system files
@echo off
>myJars.txt (
  for %%D in (.) do (
    for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
      'dir /b /a-d *.jar'
    ) do (echo ^<jar href="%%~nD/%%F"/^>)
  )
)
```

Comment: I'll give this top answer for two reasons:

1.  You made it more readable and more approachable for people that come later.

2. You did it without files / variables.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that my batch-fu is way strong:

```
@echo off
dir /b /A *.jar > myJars.txt
for %%* in (.) do set CurrDirName=%%~n*
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myJars.txt) do echo ^<jar href^="%CurrDirName%/%%A" /^> >> myJars2.txt
```

Comment: +1, That works, but you don't need the temp file or the environment variable. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13692955/1012053)